# NumericRangeFilter not working Lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to add search filter to products depending on price.

```
Lucene.Net.Search.Filter filter = NumericRangeFilter.NewFloatRange("AnalyzedPrice", minPrice, maxPrice, true, true);
```

But its Not returning any results. When I pass this filter as null output given is correct.

I am indexing my products' price using

```
doc.Add(new Field("AnalyzedPrice", pv.Price.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`NumericField`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d5/d8e/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_documents_1_1_numeric_field.html) class for range queries to work (or `FloatField` for instance if you're using a more recent Lucene version through IKVM).

This class will encode your field data - it will not be stored textually anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Following line solved my issue

```
doc.Add(new NumericField("AnalyzedPrice", Field.Store.YES, true).SetFloatValue((float)pv.Price));
```